# Hide first <td> if second in <td> is not selected any value (empty)

Tags: php, wordpress

I need hide first one < td > `<?php echo $user_feature['tab_title_single']; ?>` if second < td > are abolutely empty without any checked ('tab_title_labels') values.

```
<?php
    if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }

    if (!empty($id)) {
        $post_id = $id;
    }
    $user_features = array(
        array(
            'tab_title_single' => 'Apsauga',
            'tab_title_labels' => 'Imobilaizeris,Signalizacija,Palydovinė sekimo sistema,Šarvuotas (apsaugos)'
        ),
        array(
            'tab_title_single' => 'Audio/video įranga',
            'tab_title_labels' => 'CD grotuvas,MP3 grotuvas,Papildoma audio įranga,CD keitiklis,AUX jungtis,Žemų dažnių garsiakalbis,DVD grotuvas,USB jungtis,Laisvų rankų įranga,Apple CarPlay / Android Auto'
        ),
        array(
            'tab_title_single' => 'Eksterjeras',
            'tab_title_labels' => 'Lengvojo lydinio ratlankiai,LED dienos žibintai,LED žibintai,Žibintai „Xenon“,Rūko žibintai,Kablys,Priekinių žibintų plovimo įtaisas,Stogo bagažinės laikikliai,Automatiškai užsilenkiantys veidrodėliai,Žieminių padangų komplektas'
        ),
        array(
            'tab_title_single' => 'Elektronika',
            'tab_title_labels' => 'El. valdomi veidrodėliai,El. valdomas bagažinės dangtis,Automatiškai įsijungiantys žibintai,Borto kompiuteris,El. reguliuojama vairo padėtis,Kritulių jutiklis,Šildomi veidrodėliai,Atstumo jutiklių sistema,Beraktė sistema,Autopilotas,El. šildomas priekinis stiklas,Start-Stop funkcija,Valdymas balsu,Pavarų perjungimas prie vairo,LCD ekranas,Navigacija/GPS'
        )
    );
?>

<?php if (!empty($user_features)) {
    if (!empty($post_id)) {
        $features_car = get_post_meta($post_id, 'additional_features', true);
        $features_car = explode(',', $features_car);
    } else {
        $features_car = array();
    }
    foreach ($user_features as $user_feature) { ?>
        <table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 16%; padding-left:5px;">
                    <div class="heading-font" style="color:#555555;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 500;"><?php echo $user_feature['tab_title_single']; ?></div>
                </td>

                <td style="width: 84%; padding-left:5px;">
                    <?php $features = explode(',', $user_feature['tab_title_labels']); ?>
                    <?php if (!empty($features)): ?>
                        <?php foreach ($features as $feature): ?>
                            <?php
                                $checked = '';
                                $hide = 'style="display:none;"';

                                if (in_array($feature, $features_car)) {
                                    $checked = 'checked';
                                    $hide = '';
                                };
                            ?>
                                <label <?php echo $hide; ?>>
                                    <span class="featuresspan"><?php echo esc_attr($feature); ?></span>
                                </label>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php }
}
?>
```

Comment: Here is link to photo with exact info what I want to make. 
Link: [link]https://ibb.co/NF34sbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two arrays (`$features` and `$features_car`) in php, the most direct tool for that task is `array_intersect()`.  Although I should tell you (and researchers) that it would be far, far better to Normalize your table data so that you are not storing comma-separated values.  Having a normalized/granular table of labels and their individual features spread across multiple rows will allow your application to enjoy cleaner and more efficient queries and allow you to move the filtering processes from php to mysql where it belongs.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CfIif))

```
$features_car = ['USB jungtis', 'Rūko žibintai'];

foreach ($user_features as $user_feature) {
    $features = explode(',', $user_feature['tab_title_labels']);
    $matched_features = array_intersect($features, $features_car);
    if ($matched_features) {
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<div class=\"heading-font\">{$user_feature['tab_title_single']}</div>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    foreach ($matched_features as $show_feature) {
                        echo "<label><span class=\"featuresspan\">{$show_feature}</span></label>";
                    }
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="heading-font">Audio/video įranga</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label><span class="featuresspan">USB jungtis</span></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="heading-font">Eksterjeras</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label><span class="featuresspan">Rūko žibintai</span></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

p.s. I don't know if I support the stacking of `<table>` elements like this, but it is up to you how you wish to style your markup.  You should move ALL of your inline styles to an external stylesheet so that your markup is easier to read and manage.  I removed the `esc_attr()` only so that my demo would work without errors -- you can safely apply it to all variables that you are concerned about.